# Difference between taking $\frac{d}{dx}$ and finding derivative using First Principle

Tags: calculus

I am currently in high school and got into a loophole while studying differentiability. Normally we check if the L.H.D and R.H.D are equal at a given value of $x=a$ (given the function is continuous) but our teacher had told that it is equivalent to finding the derivative of the function $f'(x)$ by using the $\frac{d}{dx}$ operator and checking if the derivative $f'(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$. Till now this method worked just fine so I did not bother much to check if its viable or even conceptually correct.

Recently, I was introduced to this question.

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x}), & x \neq 0, \\
                   0 ,&x = 0\end{cases}$$

We are supposed to find the derivative at $x = 0$. Clearly, the function is continuous at $x = 0$. So, I proceeded to find its derivative which is $2x\sin(\frac{1}{x}) - \cos(\frac{1}{x})$. However we cant put $x = 0$ in the function as its not in the domain, so it is not continuous at $x = 0$ and hence I concluded that the function is not differentiable. However later looking at the solution I saw that the derivative does indeed exist at is equal to $0$. If we try to proceed to by the First Principle we get $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{h^2\sin(\frac{1}{h})}{h}$$ which is equal to $0$ by Sandwhich Theorem or the Squeeze Theorem. This puzzled me as I had thought that finding the derivative using $\frac{d}{dx}$ is basically derived from the First Principle and both should give the same conclusion. I thought that $f'(x)$ grahically represents the slope for $f(x)$ but this example shows that the slope at $x = 0$ exists even thought $f'(0)$ does not. Is this a misconception? If so could someone kindly explain the difference between the both.

Comment: What your teacher said is not correct or you might have misinterpreted it slightly. When the derivative is continuous, then you can calculate the derivative at $0$ by taking the limit of the derivative. However, if derivative is discontinuous at $0$, then the method is inconclusive. That is it doesn't tell you wheter the derivative exists or not, and you will therefore have to use another method, such as going through first principles.

Comment: The first derivative is not
$$2x\sin(\frac1x)-\cos(\frac1x)$$
. It's
$$2x\sin(\frac1x)+\cos(\frac1x)$$
With my correction to my correction, (LOL) it becomes more of a minor point.

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen got it , I guess I might have misinterpreted what my teacher had said.